# An ellipse is tangent to a straight line

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Given a straight line $L$: $\frac{x}{A}+\frac{y}{B}=1$, where $A$, $B>0$. Find the sufficient and necessary condition under which the following conditions hold.

1. The quadratic curve $E$: $a\,x^2+b\,x\,y+c\,y^2+d\,x+e\,y+f=0$ is an ellipse with the center below $L$.
2. $E$ is tangent to $L$ at one point $P$ in the first quadrant.
3. The center of the ellipse is below $L$ and the intercepts of the ellipse to the x-axis and to the y-axis are both positive.

My question is that do there exist some conditions in 1~3 which are redundant, i.e. can we actually remove some condition(s) such that the problem still has the same solution. Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: "The center is below the line" is not very mathematical; it should be replaced by "Let $(x_C,y_C$ be the coordinates of the center ; then $x_C/A+y_C/B<1$... giving a half of the first condition...

Comment: Should constraint 3 be read as saying that *both* $x$-intercepts are positive and *both* $y$-intercepts are positive? As written, it’s ambiguous and can be read as implying that there’s only one $x$-intercept and only one $y$-intercept, which is equivalent to saying that the ellipse must be tangent to the positive coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer.

The type of a conic section (ellipse, hyperbola, parabola...) has to do with two determinants associated with the matrix corresponding to the quadratic equation, i.e.,

$$\tag{1}A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b/2&d/2\\b/2&c&e/2\\d/2&e/2&f\end{pmatrix}$$

i.e., its own determinant and the determinant of the upper $2 \times 2$ block

$$\tag{2}B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b/2\\b/2&c\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here is a computational approach that apparently doesn't use (1) or (2).

We can express that :

$$\tag{3} a\,x^2+b\,x\,y+c\,y^2+d\,x+e\,y+f=0$$

is the equation of an ellipse as follows by considering (3) as an equation in $y$ ; $a,b,c,d,e,f$ **and** x being considered as parameters. As such:

$$\tag{4}c\,y^2+(bx+e)y+(ax^2+dx+f)=0 \  \ \iff \ \ y=\dfrac{1}{2c}(-bx-e\pm\sqrt{\Delta}) \ \ \text{the pair of cartesian equations for the ellipse}$$

$$\text{where} \ \Delta:=b^2x^2+2bex+e^2-4acx^2-4cdx-4cf \ \ \text{classical discriminant}$$

Among all types of conic curves, the ellipse is charactrized as being the only  one that is bounded, moreover such that, in particular, its projection on $x$-axis is a closed interval $[x_m,x_M]$. This condition is transferred into the condition on the cartesian equations in (1) to be defined in such an interval. It means that $\Delta$ is positive for values $x \in [x_m,x_M]$ and negative elswhere. As

$$\Delta=(b^2-4ac)x^2+2(be-2cd)x+(e^2-4cf),$$

this condition is equivalent to the following **double condition** :

- its dominant coefficient $b^2-4ac$ must be $<0$ (in order to warrant negativity for large values of $x$).
- its own discriminant $\delta:=4((be-2cd)^2-(b^2-4ac)(e^2-4cf))$ is $>0$.

But these conditions shouldn't come as a surprise. In fact, we can write:

$$\tag{5}\delta=4c(-cd^2-b^2f-ae^2+bde+4acf)$$

But the parenthesis' content in (5) is $\det(A)$ !

Now, a recap' : we can conclude that the double condition  is :

- $c.\det(A)>0 $ and
- $b^2-4ac<0$, which is equivalent to $\det(B)>0$...

Conclusion : the computation can be by-passed if these results are considered as known (you will find them in old books...).